# R: error when applying a function to a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R, and after spending some time getting familiar with basic concepts, I am now trying to write my first function. I want to use the function to make some simple calculations over a list of dataframes. My data looks like this (I have more than 100 dataframes, so this is simplified):

```
d1 <- data.frame(bp1=c(1,2,3),bp2=c(4,5,6), lp=c(4,5,6))
d2 <- data.frame(bp1=c(3,2,1),bp2=c(6,5,4), lp=c(2,1,6))
my.list <- list(d1, d2)
```

What I want to do is to take the 10^-1st column and multiply with the values in the 3rd column. Then I want to aggregate the results based on the 1st column. My function looks like this:

```
bp_calc <- function(x) {
bp1 <- x[[i]][1] 
lp <- x[[i]][3]
10^-lp * lp -> x[[i]]$p_logp
aggregate(x[[i]]$p_logp ~ bp1, data = x, sum) -> result
return(result)  
}
```

To use the function on my data, I use:

```
lapply(my.list,bp_calc)
```

However, this is throwing the error: Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds. I have of course tried to google this and seaching in this forum, but I just cannot understand what I am doing wrong. Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: and where does `i` come into play. I can at least run it by changing `bp1 <- x[[i]][1]; lp <- x[[i]][3]` to `bp1 <- x[,1]; lp <- x[,3]` and removing the other `[[i]]`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `transform` to create the new variable `p_logp` and use it as the `data` in `aggregate`

```
bp_calc <- function(x) {
  aggregate(p_logp~bp1, transform(x, p_logp=10^-lp*lp), sum)
 }

lapply(my.list, bp_calc)
```

Comment: Thanks $akrun! It seems like a much simpler way (at least less code), but I am hesitant to use it since I don't really understand what transform is doing. I looked it up, and the description is: "transform is a generic function, which—at least currently—only does anything useful with data frames. transform.default converts its first argument to a data frame if possible and calls transform.data.frame"... This didn't really help me, but maybe you have a better explanation?

Comment: @lpoulsen I am creating a new variable `p_logp`inside the dataframe  `x` where `x` is the list element of `my.list`.  One way to check what transform is doing is by separating that argument and run it separately, ie. `lapply(my.list, function(x) transform(x, p_log=10^-lp*lp))`.  From your example, you were creating a new variable from list of dataframes.

Comment: @lpoulsen `transform` returns a data.frame, so what he's doing is really: `x_transformed <- transform(x, p_logp=10^-lp*lp); aggregate(p_logp~bp1, x_transformed, sum)`

Comment: @lpoulsen No problem and thanks to ssdecontrol for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

`subscript out of bounds` means that you're trying to access a nonexistent list element. For example:

```
l <- as.list(letters[1:3])
l[4]  # returns list(NULL)
l[[4]]  # error
```

So why is this happening? Look carefully at your code. `lapply(my.list, bp_calc)` extracts each element of `my.list` and passes it to the first argument of `bp_calc`. In this case,  each list element is a data frame and `i` is never defined anywhere in this process.

So R searches for a variable called `i` in the environment where `bp_calc` was defined. In that case, either it finds `i`, or it doesn't and returns an error. Here R is finding `i` defined somewhere else, because otherwise it would say `object 'i' not found`. And whatever that `i` is, it apparently isn't any one of `1`, `2`, `3`, `bp1`, `bp2`, or `lp`.

<strike>What you need to do here is to either define `i` inside the function, or define it globally (not recommended because that's how bugs like this arise in the first place), or pass it in as an explicit argument (recommended):</strike>

```
bp_calc <- function(x, i) {
    # stuff
}
lapply(my.list, bp_calc, i = something)
```

And what is R trying to do with `i`? It's trying to access the element `i` of `x`, and then access element `1` or `3` of `x[[i]]`. Remember, `x` is *one data frame*, not a list of data frames, because `lapply` breaks apart `my.list` *before* `bp_calc` is called. It seems like you were thinking `x[[i]]` would access the "current" list element, but in reality `x` *itself* is the current list element, so `x[[i]]` is actually the "i-th element of the current element of `my.list`." So `x[[i]][3]` is "the third element of the ith element of the current element of `my.list`".

What you want is this:

```
bp_calc <- function(x) {
    bp1 <- x[[1]]
    lp <- x[[3]]
    10^-lp * lp -> x$p_logp
    aggregate(x$p_logp ~ bp1, data = x, sum)
    # by the way, R functions automatically return the last evaluated expression
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was nice with a detailed explanation $ssdecontrol! Correct me if I am wrong, but does this mean that I should define 'i', as each of the dataframes in the list that I want to use my function on? E.g. for the dataframes 1 and 2 in my.list: bp_calc <- function(x, i) {
    # stuff
}
lapply(my.list, bp_calc, i = 1:2)

Comment: No, but I just now realized what you were trying to do with `i`. I'll make an edit in a little while